# For a double integral over space variable and time variable, how to justify taking the derivative inside the outer integral?

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
$$u(x,t)=\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} \Gamma (x-y,t-s) f(y) dy ds,$$
where $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function such that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Gamma(x-y, t-s) \le \frac{C}{\left(|x-y|^2+(t-s)\right)^2}, \quad \forall 0<s<t, x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$
My question is how to justify that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,t)=\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Gamma (x-y,t-s) f(y) dy ds.$$

I tried to use dominated convergence theorem and mean value theorem, but it seems it didn't work. I got stuck here. Any comments would be really appreciated.

Comment: So, basically you seek verification that for constant $a,b$ and multivariate function $g$ that partial diffential is distributable across the linear operation.:$$\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}\int_a^b g(x,s)\mathsf d s = \int_a^b \dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}g(x,s)\mathsf d s$$
... in the same way that it is for countable addition: $$\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}\sum_{k\in N} g(x,k)=\sum_{k\in N}\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x} g(x,k)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\Gamma \equiv 1$ then the hypothesis is satisfied but $u$ is not even defined. Some more assumptions on $\Gamma $ are necessary.